# How to generate list of Lenses?

Tags: haskell, lenses, haskell-lens

I have a common pattern in my code where I have a list of objects, and I pass them to a function `choose` to have the user select one.

```
choose :: [a] -> (a -> String) -> IO Int
```

However, returning an `Int` is unfortunate, because now I have to use the partial `(!!)` to access the chosen element. To avoid this, I would prefer to have

```
choose :: [a] -> [Lens' [a] a] -> (a -> String) -> IO (Lens' [a] a)
```

where I pass in a list of lenses, one to access each element of the list. Then, I can be sure that it is safe to use modify the object at the other end of the lens, without worrying about whether or not it actually exists.

How could I create such a list of Lenses? Effectively, I need

```
makeAccessors :: [a] -> [Lens' [a] a]
```

As a bonus, something more general like

```
makeAccessors' :: a -> Traversal' a b -> [Lens' a b]
```

would be great too - making a lens for each point the traversal accesses

Comment: why not have `choose` return the chosen object? `choose :: [a] -> (a -> String) -> IO a`

Comment: well, I am operating inside (effectively) some `StateT [a] IO` monad. I would like to then modify my monadic state, which a lens allows me to do. Currently I'm using an `Int` to know which part of my state to modify, but this requires `(!!)` (as far as I can tell)

Comment: I think what you want is the Traversal itself

Comment: I don't see what you mean. I'm looking for something that modifies just one element, not all of them. Of course I can do something like `fromJust $ myList ^? traverse . ix i`, where `i` is the chosen index, but then I still have a partial function involved - If I could split the traversal up into a list of Lenses, then I could just pick one, rather than using an unsafe indexing operation

Answer (score 1):

Maybe instead of a Lens, a [Zipper](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Zipper)?

```
data ListZipper a = LZ { left :: [a], focus :: a, right :: [a] }

listToListZipper :: [a] -> Maybe (ListZipper a)
listToListZipper (a:as) = Just $ LZ [] a as
listToListZipper []     = Nothing

modifyFocus :: (a -> a) -> ListZipper a -> ListZipper a
modifyFocus f z = z { focus = f $ focus z }

goRight :: ListZipper a -> Maybe (ListZipper a)
goRight (LZ ls l (a:rs)) = Just $ LZ (l:ls) a rs
goRight _                = Nothing

goLeft :: ListZipper a -> Maybe (ListZipper a)
goLeft (LZ (a:ls) r rs) = Just $ LZ ls a (r:rs)
goLeft _                = Nothing

listZipperToList :: ListZipper a -> [a]
listZipperToList (LZ ls a rs) = reverse ls ++ a:rs
```

It's easy to access the desired element (with `modifyFocus`), and you can make your `choose`

```
choose :: [a] -> (a -> String) -> MaybeT IO (ListZipper a)
choose as f = do 
    i <- lift $  choose' as f
    let z = listToListZipper as
    MaybeT . return $ goto i z
  where choose' :: [a] -> (a -> String) -> IO Int
        choose' = ...
        goto :: Int -> ListZipper a -> Maybe (ListZipper a)
        goto 0 z = return z
        goto n z = do
          z' <- goRight z
          goto (n-1) z'
```

or even

```
forceValidChoice :: [a] -> (a -> String) -> IO (ListZipper a)
forceValidChoice as f = do
  mz <- runMaybeT $ choose as f
  maybe (forceValidChoice as f) return mz
```